# IIB: SOAPReply encountered an error while processing a reply message

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, ibm-integration-bus

I created a flow by using SOAP Nodes with SOAPRequest to call a web service then deploy it and test it successfully

> ```
> BIP3752E: The SOAP Reply node 'CountryInfoService.MyFlow.SOAP Reply'
> encountered an error while processing a reply message. An error
> occurred during reply message processing. See previous error messages
> to determine the cause of the error. :
> C:\ci\product-build\WMB\src\WebServices\WSLibrary\ImbSOAPReplyNode.cpp:
> 310: ImbSOAPReplyNode::evaluate: ComIbmSOAPReplyNode:
> CountryInfoService.MyFlow#FCMComposite_1_2
>
>
>
> BIP3605E: The SOAP logical tree cannot be serialized. There is a
> problem with the SOAP logical tree format. Review further error
> messages for an indication to the cause of the error. Check that the
> SOAP logical supplied is correctly formatted. :
> C:\ci\product-build\WMB\src\WebServices\WSLibrary\ImbSOAPParser.cpp:
> 1449: ImbSOAPParser::refreshBitStreamFromElementsInner
>
>
>
> BIP3603E: The SOAP logical tree is missing the required ''SOAP.Body''
> element. A required element is missing from the tree. Check that the
> SOAP logical tree was correctly constructed
> ```

Why do I get this error.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:soapui]?

Comment: Nour - Just to clarify, have you created a flow with SoapInputNode -> Compute -> SoapReply node and you are using another flow with SoapRequest node to call the previous flow. If yes, then looks like in you compute node, your SOAP structure formation is missing the soap body as per your error message. <soap:Body>
...
  <soap:Fault>
  ...
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>                      Put your flow in debug mode and check the tree structure or dump the whole tree in a file using trace node.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have passed your message tree to the SOAP reply node, but the *domain* of that message tree is not SOAP. Perhaps if you are passing an XML message then the domain might be XMLNSC instead of SOAP.

If my guess is correct then you can fix this by adding a SOAPEnvelope node before the SOAPReply node. Either way, you should probably check the message tree structure in the debugger or by using a Trace node.